# run react native on ios device without expo

Tags: iphone, react-native, expo

I created my app on MAC via "create-react-native-app". Currently, I am able to run the app in the ios simulator. Is it possible to run this app on my iphone device without using expo or uploading it to store?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, your options are:

1. [Detach to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach) and build in Xcode.

Or

2. [Build a standalone app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) with `exp build:ios` and uploading the .ipa to [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).